# Listing the range from A-Z with special characters in JSX

Tags: react.js, typescript, jsx

For generating a list of characters, I currently use a static list, 2 components and some unclear conditional renders.

```
export const chars = [
  '#',
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D',
  'E',
  'F',
  'G',
  'H',
  'I',
  'J',
  'K',
  'L',
  'M',
  'N',
  'O',
  'P',
  'Q',
  'R',
  'S',
  'T',
  'U',
  'V',
  'W',
  'X',
  'Y',
  'Z',
  '*',
] as const

export type Char = typeof chars[number]


const CharItem: React.FC<{ active: boolean; onClick: () => void }> = ({
  active,
  onClick,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <li className="inline-flex items-center align-middle">
      <button
        className={cn(
          active && 'bg-gray-900 text-white',
          'inline-flex items-center align-middle py-2 px-4 font-medium text-sm'
        )}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
    </li>
  )
}

export const Charbar: React.FC<{
  active: Char
  onClick: (char: Char) => void
}> = ({ active, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-center ">
      <ul className="bg-white rounded-md divide-x divide-gray-100 text-gray-700 shadow-md">
        {chars.map((v, i) => (
          <CharItem active={v === active} onClick={() => onClick(v)} key={i}>
            {v === '#' ? (
              <HiOutlineHashtag className="h-4 w-4" />
            ) : v === '*' ? (
              <HiOutlineStar className="h-4 w-4" />
            ) : (
              v
            )}
          </CharItem>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to do this more clean? Note that the components, and `chars` variable are split over multiple files, but pasted in here for easy reading.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would split the `chars` arrays into two: the one with alphabet and the other one with soecial chars.

If you did not do it I assume you have a reason.
But we still can obtain all special chars from `chars` array in generic way:

```js
export const chars = [
  '#',
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D',
  'E',
  'F',
  'G',
  'H',
  'I',
  'J',
  'K',
  'L',
  'M',
  'N',
  'O',
  'P',
  'Q',
  'R',
  'S',
  'T',
  'U',
  'V',
  'W',
  'X',
  'Y',
  'Z',
  '*',
] as const

export type Char = typeof chars[number]

type ObtainSpecialCharacters<T> =
  (T extends string
    ? (Uppercase<T> extends Lowercase<T>
      ? T : never)
    : never)

// "#" | "*"
type Hash = ObtainSpecialCharacters<Char>
```

Just check whether uppercased char extends same lowercased or not. Because if it extends, then it is a special char.

Now, we can implement some logic for hash/special chars rendering:

```js
const HashTags = {
  '#': <div>{'HiOutlineHashtag'}</div>,
  '*': <div>{'HiOutlineStar'}</div>
} as const;

const RenderHash: FC<{ hash: Hash }> = ({ hash }) => HashTags[hash]

const isHash = (str: Char): str is Hash => /\*|#/.test(str)
```

I have used `isHash` custom typeguard to check whether char is a special char or just a regular one.

The whole code:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export const chars = [
  '#',
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D',
  'E',
  'F',
  'G',
  'H',
  'I',
  'J',
  'K',
  'L',
  'M',
  'N',
  'O',
  'P',
  'Q',
  'R',
  'S',
  'T',
  'U',
  'V',
  'W',
  'X',
  'Y',
  'Z',
  '*',
] as const

export type Char = typeof chars[number]

type ObtainSpecialCharacters<T> =
  (T extends string
    ? (Uppercase<T> extends Lowercase<T>
      ? T : never)
    : never)

// "#" | "*"
type Hash = ObtainSpecialCharacters<Char>

const CharItem: React.FC<{ active: boolean; onClick: () => void }> = ({
  active,
  onClick,
  children,
}) => (
  <li>
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  </li>
)

const HashTags = {
  '#': <div>{'HiOutlineHashtag'}</div>,
  '*': <div>{'HiOutlineStar'}</div>
} as const;

const RenderHash: FC<{ hash: Hash }> = ({ hash }) => HashTags[hash]

const isHash = (str: Char): str is Hash => /\*|#/.test(str)

export const Charbar: React.FC<{
  active: Char
  onClick: (char: Char) => void
}> = ({ active, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {chars.map((v, i) => (
          <CharItem active={v === active} onClick={() => onClick(v)} key={i}>
            {isHash(v) ? <RenderHash hash={v} /> : v}
          </CharItem>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDNIAekscaEAdgGd4aABYooAuAF44AbWZw6AYlqYFdAIKr1tAELbFtQgboARE7QCiF-BYDiFgBIWAkhYBSFgNIWAMhYBZCwA5CwB5CwAFCwBFCwQLAGULABULAFULADULAHULAA0LAE0LAC0LACptAF04FEleQRhWDi54GABPMCQ4QjEoaTgunohyHgGBWT4AVxAAIyQoGtYR3rD5mBRgPkSetGAUABt%208XQYJYEAHhSAPml1AAoUuA4LvgATSSEoHYBzdSKAD8cEe6TAPSgaAaSBu9zeSE%20kl8EAA7ktoQJYXdAYo4CCXgAuOB8JAANyWAEpccTSRSoNTmAB6JlwABESjZcAAPuzKmzmGs4I4GiIhhstjs9kgDsdTlBzpcrvLbqwmkI%20gMXBcQMTkOcAHREK54c7ACnE%20YQCBHVB8ADccH4hCOwDQAGtiY9KdJ7mSIMAPqR7jJHjh1GaKWpFM7XR7oxNgEcPgw%20GoSD6pPdHuorq7VXi4Fd5jMYDB%20LiY3wXW73VIcLHayRcQXC7hREmU4jm4WrkyS2X%20K2%20-nmIz1fARQIRCkUH9JDJw4YVMSrh9zbccLRHMAwqXXaSpyItn9aCQ%20%20uybcE7RqqvL5vt7v9zskIktlAzxeN8wyA0ePwQj2mqgHwMgnxLEexLGngYjTsSR7BkMYZwHBYoZr6wqirO86yGhKzMBOcDAAIiGhj8xLypSxI-MRkhkfcTIADqVNyShMgaFxCI8PyMm00DCKBmriPM4h6owMBGoQJoRhg5pIJRAzqI2HpeqIYnCQymH%20oGv4hqCppyVGTrVnG7qkJm9xLnADAwDMUB8KCuJXHwKBXpWRYzEcrZtu2kwGiAKBgI8jxktgwCWU5vm9vK2pIDQkZIPWZLSFIMiJWQKl1jg3qYVloWUmQ7pIJ09bACQPnRYoOAkUeBX4kW4EfJBoqoaKyVkEy9zEmSPZVUWTKxTqlWFpShUeX2XmVX2rnuYo1IkEAA)